# Why am I getting a system identifier error with my google app script

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, google-apps-script

I'm using the following Google Apps Script to do some screen scraping.

```
function getLinks(html) {
  var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
  var html = doc.getRootElement();
  var table = getElementsByClassName(html, "headLinks")[0];
  var output = '';
  var linksInMenu = getElementsByTagName(table, 'a');
  for(i in linksInMenu) output+= XmlService.getRawFormat().format(linksInMenu[i])+'<br>';
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);
}
```

The first line of code: **var doc = XmlService.parse(html)**; is throwing the following error:

```
Error on line 2: The system identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character
```

I believe the error message is telling me that the html there are no single or double quotes around the system Id.  Line 2 of the html follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I not sure what is meant by system identifer. Has anyone run into to this problem and have you been able to come up with a workaround or solution.

The Google Apps Script code comes from Romain Vialard's: [website](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html)

Answer (score 1):

The `parse` method takes a parameter of `xml`.  The first line of XML typically starts with an XML declaration, with version and encoding information.  Both HTML and XML can have a system identifier that starts with `<!DOCTYPE`, that is on the second line.  The accepted syntax for the system identifier is:

```
<!DOCTYPE root-element PUBLIC "FPI" ["URI"] [ 
<!-- internal subset declarations -->
]>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE root-element SYSTEM "URI" [ 
<!-- internal subset declarations -->
]>
```

I ran a test function with hard coded data:

```
function testXML_Parse() {

  var theXML_Declaration = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  var theXML = "<note><to>Someone</to><from>Anyone</from><heading>Reminder</heading>" +
    "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";

  var theSysIdentifier = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';
  var doc = XmlService.parse(theXML_Declaration + theSysIdentifier + theXML);

  Logger.log('doc: ' + doc);
}
```

I used the exact same second line that you gave, and didn't have any errors.

Without all the data that is being passed into the `html` variable, there is an unknown that can't be tested.